# Polylang version 3 has a bug and it is incompatible with Advance Custom Field (ACF)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, polylang

Polylang version 2 is working well with Advance Custom Field (ACF)

I want to update my website and use the latest version of Polylang which is version 3.3.3

in this situation I can see a bug in Polylang:

1- I create an article and add an image in ACF

2- save the article

3- translate the article to another language

and here is the result: it doesn't show the media in translated articles.

[image]

and after I click on the plus button to translate it to another language, as you can see there is no image.

[image]

but in Polylang version 2, I have the image after I translate it.

here is a video about the bug:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/c8sac0rp3bmujca/polylang_3_bug.mp4/file

I know if in the polylang settings, in `languages` -> `settings` -> `media` -> `Media Automatically duplicate media in all languages when uploading a new file.` if I check this option it will duplicate the image, when I upload and will work... but I don't want to have duplicated images.

I want only one image when I upload an image. (like polylang version 2).

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article: [Polylang - working with media](https://polylang.pro/doc/working-with-media/)

Polylang does not duplicate the images. It stores additional metadata in wp_metadata.
When you translate an image, you are just translating the name, caption and alt text and those are the strings stored.